# Python: Timing out a function that is called in a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout

I have a process that spawns new threads and does work, when the threads are done I start a new batch of threads.  I have an issue where a thread may do an RPC call that sometimes never returns.  The RPC unfortunately does not support a timeout feature.  I know we can use signals to help timeout a function but since this is multi-threaded I can't utilize that.  Is there any recommended way to timeout a function that is called in a thread to a set interval?

Answer (score 0):

To know how to stop/kill threads, you should check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/7344150). As for timing out, if your main thread is waiting for the batch of subthreads to finish, then you can use a standard timer `time.time()` and then after a sufficient amount of time, use the methods shown in the other answer.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to timeout a function rather than the whole thread if possible.